# How can I call this simple API using POST/GET

Tags: json, http, localhost

I have this URL which simply open my garage door by clicking it, the garage opener is locally hosted.
I'm trying to use API call in which use this URL to simply simulate garage door click.

The URL is: https://MY-SERVER-URL/cc?dkey=abc&click=1

The API Code is like this:

```
    {
        "name": "Garage Door",
        "simulateTimeOpening": 10,
        "simulateTimeOpen": 60,
        "simulateTimeClosing": 10,
        "closeAfter": 60,
        "request": {
            "url": "MY-SERVER-URL?",
            "method": "POST",
            "type": "JSON",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "cc",
                    "value": "?"
                }
            ],
            "params": [
                {
                    "name": "dkey",
                    "value": "abc"
                },
                {
                    "name": "click",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "accessory": "HttpGarageDoors"
    }
```

it is giving me error and not firing the request, what am I doing wrong?

```
    {
        "name": "Garage Door",
        "simulateTimeOpening": 10,
        "simulateTimeOpen": 60,
        "simulateTimeClosing": 10,
        "closeAfter": 60,
        "request": {
            "url": "MY-SERVER-URL?",
            "method": "POST",
            "type": "JSON",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "cc",
                    "value": "?"
                }
            ],
            "params": [
                {
                    "name": "dkey",
                    "value": "azsxdcfv"
                },
                {
                    "name": "click",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "accessory": "HttpGarageDoors"
    }
```

Comment: from the API docs: Change Controller Variables:
http://devip/cc?dkey=xxx&click=1
Parameters:
● dkey:  device key (factory default device key is opendoor)
● click:  trigger relay click / close open door

Comment: I don't see an error